# xstring - How to define a macro that removes final punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, strings, xstring

Is it possible to create a command to remove final punctuation from a sentence (here to simplify, just remove the final period)?

Thanks to the `xstring` package, I can remove the final punctuation for a simple sentence, but it doesn't work if the sentence is included in `\textit`, `\textbf` etc.

Is it possible to tell `xstring` to ignore such commands and only look at their argument?

After reading the documentation, I didn't see a command to do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\removePunct}[1]{{\exploregroups%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\resultA]
    \IfEndWith{\resultA}{.}{%
        \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\resultB]%
        \resultB%
    }{#1}
}}

\begin{document}
\removePunct{This is a test.}

\removePunct{{This is a test.}}

\removePunct{\textit{This is a test.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\textit{\removePunct{This is a test.}}`?

Comment: @Niranjan Unfortunately, the context of use of this command does not allow it :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of variety, let's also consider a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a LaTeX utility macro called `\RemovePunct`, which in turn calls a Lua function called `removepunct` to do most of the work. `removepunct` employs Lua's versatile `string.gsub` function, which makes use of Lua's powerful pattern matching and capture capabilities.

Note that this solution removes punctuation characters only if they occur at the end of the argument of `\RemovePunct` (other than any closing curly braces and whitespace). It'll remove both single and multiple instances of such punctuation characters. Any whitespace in the argument of `\RemovePunct` after the final punctuation mark is also removed.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode*' environment and '\luastringN' macro
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
   function removepunct ( s )
      tex.sprint ( ( s:gsub ( "%p*([}%s]-)$" , function ( v )
                                 return ( v:gsub ( "%s" , "" ) )
                              end ) ) )
   end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand{\RemovePunct}[1]{\directlua{removepunct(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\RemovePunct{This is a test. This is also a test. }

\RemovePunct{{This is a test. Is this also a test? }  }

\RemovePunct{\textit{This is a test. This is indeed a test! } }

\RemovePunct{\textit{\textbf{This is a test. This is also a test!!! } }}

\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, about the meaning of the Lua code chunk in the answer shown above.

- The "sprint" in `tex.sprint` is short for "string print", *not* "run very fast for a short period of time".
- The "gsub" in `string.gsub` is short for "general subsitution". The code chunk actually contains 2 `string.gsub` instructions.
- The "inner" one -- `v:gsub ( "%s" , "" )` -- serves to purge whitespace characters, denoted by the "magic" character `%s`, from the search string.
- The outer one starts with `s:gsub ( "%p*([}%s]-)$"`. This means that it operates on `s` (which is a string passed to the Lua function by the `\RemovePunct` macro) and employs the search string

  ```
  %p*([}%s]-)$
  ```

  There are three main components to this search string: `%p*`, `([}%s]-)`, and `$`. Let's work from back to front: In a Lua search pattern, `$` denotes "end of string", i.e., it serves as an "anchor": only the very last parts of a string will be considered in the search. `[}%s]` sets up a Lua "character class", consisting of two characters: `}` ("closing curly brace"), and `%s` -- the "magic character that denotes any whitespace character. `[}%s]-` means "0 or more instances of characters in the `[}%s]` character class. The round parentheses around `[}%s]-` denote a Lua *capture*, i.e., a pattern match will be treated as a capture that can be addressed as a whole during the string replacement phase. Finally, `%p` is the Lua "magic character" for "any punctuation character". A Lua punctuation character is not just one of the sentence-ending variety characters, `.?!`, but also `,`, `;`, and even `+-*/`, plus a few more. `%p*` denotes "0 or more punctuation-type characters (greedy)".

  Putting everything together in the search string `%p*([}%s]-)$`, we see that it means "0 or more punctuation type characters (greedy), followed by 0 or more instances of `%s` (whitespace) or `}` (non-greedy), followed by the end-of-line signifier `$`. If a pattern match occurs, the `[}%s]-` portion is "captured". Observe that the search pattern does not care about what happens earlier in the string `s`; that's by design.
- This brings us to the string *replacement* action of the "outer" `string.gsub` directive. Frequently, this will be a static string. For the solution at hand, however, it's "dynamic", in the sense that it's given by a Lua *function*:

  ```
  function ( v ) 
     return ( v:gsub ( "%s" , "" ) ) 
  end
  ```

  Recall that the search part looked for strings that match the pattern `%p*([}%s]-)$` and that if a match occurs, the `[}%s]-` is captured as an entity in and of itself. Since the function takes only one argument, `v`, this argument must be the contents of the capture. (If there were 3 captures in the search string, they'd be addressed as, say, `function (u,v,w)`.) Aside: since `%p*` is *not* placed in a capture, it is discarded at this point; that's what we wanted all along, wasn't it? As discussed earlier, the function operates on `v` by discarding whitespace.

Let's see how this all comes together by examining what happens when LaTeX encounters

```
\RemovePunct{\textit{This is a test. This is indeed a test! } }
```

The argument of this command is

```
|\textit{This is a test. This is indeed a test! } |
```

where `|` denotes the start and end of the argument. Observe that the last few characters of the argument are `test! }`  and that there's whitespace both before and after `}`. The `\luastringN` macro places this argument *without expansion* into a string that's passed to our favorite Lua function for further processing; our Lua function refers to this input argument as `s`. A pattern match occurs, and hence `s` is transformed to

```
|\textit{This is a test. This is indeed a test}|
```

Observe that the final punctuation character `!` *and* the trailing whitespace characters are gone. The Lua function passes this modified string to the `tex.sprint` function for final disposition. (If you are eagle-eyed, you may notice that the argument of `tex.sprint` is encased in *two pairs*, not one pair, of round parentheses. This is deliberate. The reason is that `string.gsub` actually returns 2 outputs: (a) the replacement string(s) and (b) the number of times a replacement was performed. Encasing the output of `gsub` in an extra pair of parentheses is a quick and easy way of discarding the second argument.)

I hope this helps.

---

---

*Second addendum*, to address the OP's question about how to suppress `\dots`, `\ldots`, and `\textellipsis` if they occur at the *end* of the argument of `\RemovePunct` (other than, possibly, closing curly braces and whitespace).

This added objective could probably be handled in many different ways. An easy (and, hopefully, easy-to-understand) way is to add the instructions

```lua
      s = s:gsub ( "\\textellipsis([}%s]-)$" , "%1" )
      s = s:gsub ( "\\l?dots([}%s]-)$" , "%1"
```

right after the start of the `removepunct` Lua function. This approach should not entail significant overhead -- unless you start to purge lots and lots of TeX macros at the end of the argument of `\RemovePunct`.

The revised/augmented `removepunct` function would thus look like this:

```lua
   function removepunct ( s )
      s = s:gsub ( "\\textellipsis([}%s]-)$" , "%1" )
      s = s:gsub ( "\\l?dots([}%s]-)$" , "%1" )
      s = s:gsub ( "%p*([}%s]-)$" , function ( v )
                       return ( v:gsub ( "%s" , "" ) )
                    end ) 
      tex.sprint ( s )
   end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain me the following syntax? `tex.sprint ( ( s:gsub ( "%p*([}%s]-)$" , function ( v ) return ( v:gsub ( "%s" , "" ) ) end ) ) )`

Comment: @Bastien - I just finished posting the addendum. I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: After a few days of testing, it turns out that your solution seems the most versatile, so I accepted your solution. Nevertheless, I will ask you the same question as for Egreg's answer : how to make Lua ignore `\ldots` and `\textellipsis` ?

Comment: @Bastien - By "ignore `\ldots` and `\textellipsis`", do you mean (a) "don't do anything to `\ldots` and `\textellipsis`", or do you actually mean (b) *purge* `\ldots` and `\textellipsis` from the input stream? Please advise.

Comment: More like (b). I'd like `This is a test\ldots` or `This is a test\textellipsis` to be rendered `This is a test` (without the three dots) if possible.

Comment: @Bastien - Please see the 2nd addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Easy with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removePunct}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\,|\;|\:|\.|\!|\?) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\removePunct{This has, as you see, no punctuation; really. Really?!}

\removePunct{\textit{This has, \textbf{as you see}, \textsc{no} punctuation; really. Really?!}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just want to remove a trailing period:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removePunct}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\,|\;|\:|\.|\!|\?) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeFinalPeriod}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \.([^[:alpha:]]*) \Z } { \1 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
  
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\removePunct{This has, as you see, no punctuation; really. Really?!}

\removePunct{\textit{This has, \textbf{as you see}, \textsc{no} punctuation; really. Really?!}}

\removeFinalPeriod{This has no period.}

\removeFinalPeriod{This has no period}

\removeFinalPeriod{\textit{This has no period.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for introducing me to the syntax of `expl3` which I don't know.

Comment: Just a small point of clarification: how do you remove the ellipsis? `\regex_replace_once:nnN{\,|\;|\:|\.|\!|\?|\ldots|\textellipsis ([^[:alpha:]]*) \Z}{\1} \l_tmpa_tl` does not seem to work.

Comment: @Bastien `\c{ldots}` and `\c{textellipsis}`

Comment: Thank you very much ;)

Comment: How would you have to modify the code of `\removePunct` so that only the *final* punctuation mark(s), but no intermediate punctuation marks, in the argument of `\removePunct` got removed?

Comment: @Mico Transfer `(\,|\;|\:|\.|\!|\?)` in place of `\.` and change `\1` into `\2` in `\removeFinalPeriod`

Comment: Aah, sorry, I had somehow overlooked the second half of your answer, which deals precisely with my question.

Answer (score 5):

With a token cycle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\removePunct[1]{%
  \def\bufchar{}%
  \stripgroupingtrue
  \tokcycle
    {\purgebuffer\gdef\bufchar{##1}}
    {\purgebuffer\groupedcytoks{\processtoks{##1}%
      \expandafter\testbuffer\bufchar\empty}}
    {\purgebuffer\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\purgebuffer\addcytoks{##1}}
    {#1}%
  \expandafter\testbuffer\bufchar\empty
  \the\cytoks
}
\newcommand\purgebuffer{\addcytoks[1]{\bufchar}\gdef\bufchar{}}
\newcommand\testbuffer[1]{%
  \ifx.#1\else
  \ifx,#1\else
  \ifx!#1\else
  \ifx?#1\else
    \purgebuffer
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
\removePunct{This is a test.}

\removePunct{{This is a test.}}

\removePunct{\textit{This is a test?}}

\removePunct{\rule{1ex}{1ex}, \textbf{\textit{This is a test!}}}

\removePunct{\textit{This is a test. \today}}
\end{document}
```

[image]