# Conditionally remove trailing period

Tags: conditionals, punctuation, xstring

I have an abbreviation "f.o.o.". However, I might later want to change it to simply "foo". I thus define a macro in order to easily switch (by (un)commenting the relevant lines) between the two options:

```
\documentclass{article}

% f.o.o. option
\newcommand{\foo}{f.o.o.\@}
% foo option
%\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
It could be a \foo{}, but then it might not be a \foo{}.
\end{document}
```

This works just fine, except for the trailing period. If I use the foo option, then the text is displayed correctly as:

> It could be a foo, but then it might not be a foo.

However, if I use the f.o.o. option, then there's one period too many:

> It could be a f.o.o., but then it might not be a f.o.o..

Is there some clever way to dynamically remove a trailing period with the f.o.o. option? This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/617191/87397) provides a nice way to use `xstring` to remove a trailing period, but I don't know how to get `\newcommand` to look ahead to the following character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I first check whether the next token is `{`; in case it is, the contents of the braces (usually empty) is delivered and reexamined.

If a period follows, it is ignored and so the standard sentence-ending space is used; otherwise `\@` is issued.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}
 {
  f.o.o.
  \peek_catcode:NTF \c_group_begin_token
   {
    \dwolfeu_foo_brace:n
   }
   {
    \dwolfeu_foo_checkperiod:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dwolfeu_foo_brace:n
 {% deliver the argument unbraced
  \dwolfeu_foo_checkperiod: #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dwolfeu_foo_checkperiod:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF . {} { \@ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xspaceskip=20pt

It could be a \foo{}, but then it might not be a \foo{}. Text follows.

It could be a \foo, but then it might not be a \foo. Text follows.

It could be a \foo{} with normal space.

It could be a \foo. With sentence-ending space.

\end{document}
```

I used a big value of `\xspaceskip` just to better show when the sentence-ending space is used.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use only TeX primitives then you can use this code:

```
\def\foo{f.o.o.\checknextdot}
\def\checknextdot{\futurelet\next\checknextdotA}
\def\checknextdotA{\let\nextA=\relax
   \ifx\next.\def\nextA##1{}\fi
   \ifx\next\bgroup\def\nextA##1{\checknextdot}\fi
   \nextA
}
```

In OpTeX, you can use following macros:

```
\def\foo{f.o.o.\checknextdot}
\def\checknextdot{\isnextchar.{\ignoreit}%
                              {\isnextchar\bgroup{\ea\checknextdot\ignoreit}
                                                 {}}}
```

Testing code for both variants:

```
It could be a \foo{}, but then it might not be a \foo{}. Text follows.

It could be a \foo, but then it might not be a \foo. Text follows.

It could be a \foo{} with normal space.

It could be a \foo. With sentence-ending space.
```

Comment: Alas neither solution works for me: The TeX-primitives-only solution causes my console to hang, while I'm not using OpTeX and so `\isnextchar` throws an error.

Comment: @dwolfeu I created a file `test.tex` with 7 lines of "primitive" macros followed by 7 lines of testing code followed by `\bye`. Then I run `pdftex test`. Nothing hangs, pdf file is created. Second: I created `testl.tex` file with `\documentclass{article}` followed by 7 lines of the "primitive" macros followed by `\begin{document}` followed by 7 lines of testing code followed by `\end{document}`. Then I run `pdflatex testl.tex`. Nothing hangs, pdf file is created. What did you do?

Comment: I apologise: The issue was not with your solution but with the command `\titlecap{\foo{}}` (from the package `titlecaps`). Incidentally, the down-vote for your answer was not from me.